# How to use parameters in Axios (vuejs)?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Good morning Folks,

I got an API from where I am getting the data from.

I am trying to filter that with Axios but I don`t get the result that I am expecting.

I created a search box. I created a computed filter and that I applied on the Axios.

I would like to see only the searched results in my flexboxes (apart from the last three articles as a start)

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="search-bar"
        v-model="search"
        placeholder="Search in the titles"
      />
    </div>
    <paginate
      ref="paginator"
      class="flex-container"
      name="items"
      :list="filteredArticles"
    >
      <li
        v-for="(item, index) in paginated('items')"
        :key="index"
        class="flex-item"
      >
        <div id="image"><img :src="item.image && item.image.file" /></div>

        <div id="date">{{ formatDate(item.pub_date) }}</div>

        <div id="title">{{ item.title }}</div>

        <div id="article" v-html="item.details_en" target="blank">
          Explore More
        </div>
      </li>
    </paginate>
    <paginate-links
      for="items"
      :limit="2"
      :show-step-links="true"
    ></paginate-links>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      paginate: ["items"],
      search: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.loadPressRelease();
  },
  methods: {
    loadPressRelease() {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page_size=61&type=5`,
          { params }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data.results;
        });
    },
    formatDate(date) {
      return moment(date).format("ll");
    },
    openArticle() {
      window.open(this.items.details_en, "blank");
    },
  },
  computed: {
    axiosParameters() {
      const params = new SearchParams();
      if (!this.search) {
        return this.items;
      }
      return this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.title.includes(this.search);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You should add a watcher (probably with some debouncing) for the `search` variable - which will make the AJAX request any time you type something in the searchbox.

Comment: thanks Igo, do you happen to have a good tutorial for that?

Comment: The best source of information is the Vue documentation - https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic code for implementing vue watcher along with the debounce for search functionality.

```
import _ from "lodash"  // need to install lodash library

data() {
  return {
    search: "",
  };
},

watch:{
    search: _.debounce(function (newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        // place your search logic here
      } else{
        // show the data you want to show when the search input is blank
      }
    }, 1000),
}
```

**Explanation:**

We have placed a watcher on `search` variable. Whenever it detects any change in `search` variable, it will execute the `if` block of code if it's value is not empty. If the value of `search` variable goes empty, it will execute `else` block.

The role of adding `debounce` here is, it will put a delay of 1 sec in executing the block of code, as we don't want to execute the same code on every single character input in the search box. Make sure you install and import lodash library. For more info on Lodash - Debounce, please refer [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce).

**Note:** This is not the exact answer for this question, but as it is asked by the question owner in the comment section, here is the basic example with code.

Comment: hi @Sheeraj, I was told that I can use something like this: for the input please use this event and call the axios function with which you get the data in the event function
@input="changeSearchtext()"
Where do i create this function? In methods, computed? or at the axios directly?

Comment: @BalazsKelemen I am not sure why do you need to call the function in `@input` but if that is the requirement that you must create the function in `methods`. You cannot use `computed` property in `@input`.